# реализовать на js функцию addOne

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать на js функцию addOne, чтоб была возможность выводить результат в таком виде:

```js
console.log(addOne().getResult()) // 1
console.log(addOne()()().getResult()) // 3
console.log(addOne()().getResult()) // 2
```

Comment: изучить тему замыканий наверное надо

Comment: Скорее всего никак , для каких целей вам это нужно?

Comment: Не в корыстных целях, а любопытства ради. У меня есть идея, как реализовать addOne()()() c помощью рекурсии и замыкания, а так же как реализовать addOne().getResult(), и даже как сделать цепочку вызовов addOne().addOne().getResult() . Как слить это воедино придумать не могу.

Comment: @user-user Даже если у вас получится замкнуть так функции , то это не получится  замыкать до бесконечности , т.к. стеки переполнятся)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если у вас есть представление о решении,  я был бы признателен, если бы Вы натолкнули на мысль, дали бы ссылку или дали бы более развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function addOne() {
  let idx = 1;
  const res = function() {
    idx++;
    return res;
  };
  res.getResult = function() {
    return idx;
  };
  return res;
}

console.log(addOne().getResult()) // 1
console.log(addOne()()().getResult()) // 3
console.log(addOne()().getResult()) // 2
```

Идея: функция `addOne()` возвращает функцию, которая при каждом вызове увеличивает внутренний счетчик. А т.к. функции в JS - это объекты, то возвращаемый объект еще содержит поле-метод `getResult`, который возвращает текущее значение счетчика